# Remove inner padding in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, margin, bounding-box

In the code below, how do I minimize/remove the inner padding to make the green polygon span the entire gray bounding box?

```
suppressMessages(library(GISTools))
suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))
data(newhaven)

blocks_df <- fortify(blocks)
ggplot(data = blocks_df) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), fill = "darkolivegreen4") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: I think the standard term is 'margin' rather than 'padding'

Comment: @smci You are right. I guess I still haven't completely forgotten my Matlab training from decades ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `coord_equal()` layer can take an `expand` argument -- set that to `FALSE` and the plot window will fit to the plotted data's size:

```
... 
ggplot(data = blocks_df) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), fill = "darkolivegreen4") +
  # set `expand=FALSE` 
  coord_equal(expand=FALSE) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()))
```

And a quick follow-up: note that the `expand` parameter on most other coordinate layers (e.g. `scale_x_continuous()`) needs to be a vector of length two (for "multiplicative and additive expansion constants"). So you'd say e.g. `scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` in that case. :p